# How am I using read_string incorrectly?

Tags: ruby

This program is designed to ask a number of questions, and then display the entered information back to them. In a previous version, I used `gets.chomp.to_s` in various places, and it worked. But following my teacher, I replaced a number of `gets.chomp.to_s` to `read_string`, and now my program doesn't work.

```
require 'date'
INCHEs = 0.393701

def main
  first_name = read_string ('What is your first name')
  puts 'Your name is ' + first_name + '!'
  puts 'What is your family name?'
  family_name = gets.chomp.to_s
  puts 'Your family name is: ' + family_name + '!'      
  puts 'What year were you born?'
  year_born = read_string('What year were you born?')
  year_born.to_i
  # Calculate the users age
  current_year = 2019
  age = current_year - year_born
  puts 'So you are ' + age.to_s + ' years old'          
  value_in_cms = read_string('Enter your height in cms (i.e as a float): ')
  value_in_cms.to_f
  value_in_inch = value_in_cms * INCHES
  puts 'Your height in inches is: '
  puts value_in_inch.to_s       
  answer = read_string('Do you wish to continue')
  case answer
  when 'y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES'
    true
    puts 'Okay let us continue'
  else
    false
    puts 'Okay, goodbye'
  end
end

main
puts ' '
puts main
```

Where am I making errors?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better confirm with your teacher.
There is no method of `read_string` in ruby. Maybe your teacher wants you to wrap your logic in a `read_string` method.

Answer (score 1):

*Sidenote:* `to_s` in `gets.chomp.to_s` is redundant, since `gets` always returns a string by itself.

What your teacher meant is probably you should *extract* several calls to `gets.chomp` into the method, and use this method everywhere instead of `gets.chomp` as you already did:

```
def read_string(prompt)
  print(prompt + " ")
  gets.chomp
end

def main
  first_name = read_string('What is your first name')
  ...
end
```

*Sidenote #2:* never ever put spaces between the method name and the opening parenthesis in ruby.

Comment: The new school way is `gets(chomp: true)`.

Comment: @sawa yes, but then it makes zero sense to extract it into a separate method.